# Executing Command line instructions from Python with Subprocess module(Windows)

Tags: python, command-line, subprocess

I've read about Subprocess module from python documentation and from Stackoverflow as well ! But i am unable to implement the concept ! Like for example :

[image]

So how can I execute following command line using python ?

Comment: @hashcode55 Why did you change the URL when you made your edit to this question?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `subprocess.call`

```
subprocess.call(args, *, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False)
```

Here * is the bufsize, 0 means unbuffered, 1 means line buffered, any other positive value means use a buffer of approximately that size. The default value for bufsize is 0 (unbuffered).

Example (from the docs)-

```
from subprocess import call
subprocess.call(["ls", "-l"])
```

Source - https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: I have read this answer before as well could you just write the exact line ? I mean the cmd instruction is mentioned above ! Ps what is * ?

Comment: if there are multiple commands then separate them in the list , `subprocess.call("your command", shell = True)`... I can't test it as I'm using unix based system. I edited the answer too.

Comment: Thanks @hashcode55 ! It is working. I was looking for this short answer -> subprocess.call("your command",shell=True)